# Do I get an infinite loop when setting a ScrollView with a Geometry reader up?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to figure out the basics of ScrollViews in SwiftUI.
I figured if I created a `Text` with a frame of the width of the screen and .infinite height, which I understood to mean "as large as the available space, e.g. safe area", and dropped it into a `ScrollView` with another `Text` companion, I'd get a screen-sized `Text` that could scroll horizontally to the companion `Text`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                        VStack {
                            Text("crash me")
                        }
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width,
                                   height: .infinity,
                                   alignment: .topLeading)
                    }
            Text("crash me")
            
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this, it just crashes. What's so stupid about it?

Comment: Xcode gives the runtime warning: "Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite)." That should give you a good idea that you are creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @George_E yeah, I guessed as much. It's the .infinite that crashes the system.

Comment: Setting the height to `.infinite` is a problem - you may have instead meant `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)`?

Comment: @George_E Ah you nailed it. It was right in front of my nose the whole time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.frame(height: .infinity)
```

You should use:

```
.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Setting the exact height to `.infinity` is not possible, but `maxHeight` means that the view will stretch its height to the maximum value possible. This would be the size of the screen, or any other limiting factor set by the parent.